# Margin-top of not working on unfloated element

Tags: html, css

I have a parent div `#modal_share` that contains a floating div `modal_big_hline` and a unfloated div `modal_big_button_container` (with `clear: both`).

`modal_big_button_container`'s CSS is created to allow it to be the width of the parent div minus 25px on its left and right sides.

**Problem:** Changing the `margin-top` of `modal_big_button_container` does not cause it to shift up/down, instead it remains in the same position, although its margin can be seen to be changing using Chrome's developer tools.

Why is this happening, and how can I solve this? Thanks!

**CSS**

```
#modal_share {
    width: 565px;
    height: 400px;
    position: relative;
    background: whiteSmoke;
    padding-top: 10px;      
    -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
    -moz-border-radius: 10px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 3px 16px #222;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 3px 16px #222;
    box-shadow: 0px 3px 16px #222;
    display: none;  
}

.modal_big_hline {
    width: 100%;
    height: 1px;
    margin-top: 25px;
    border-top: 1px solid #CCC;
    float: left;
}

#modal_big_button_container {
    height: 14px;
    width: auto;
    margin: 10px 25px 0px 25px;
    clear: both;
}
```

**HTML Structure**

```
<div id="#modal_share">
    <div class="modal_big_hline"></div>
    <div id="modal_big_button_container"></div>
</div>
```

**JSFiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/5LG2w/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try

```
modal_big_button_container{
    position: relative;
      top: 20px;
}
```

here is the fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/5LG2w/2/.

or you can take the float out of .modal_big_hline. then your margin-top will work - http://jsfiddle.net/5LG2w/3/.

```
#modal_big_button_container {
    height: 14px;
    width: auto;
    margin: 10px 25px 0px 25px;
    clear: both;
    background: red;
}
```

Comment: Why does the to margin not work for `modal_big_button_container`? Do we really have to resort to relative positioning and defining `top`?

Comment: **float** does some pretty crazy stuff to margin an height. And probably some other things, but those are the ones that i have run into.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like margin collapsing. Check these pages:

http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/collapsingmargins

http://www.howtocreate.co.uk/tutorials/css/margincollapsing